# MYSQL Select table and column name

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a SQL query like this one :

```
SELECT T1.id, T2.user
FROM T1
INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.user_id = T2.id
```

The result is something like `id | user`.

I'd like to know if there's a way to have the same result with the table name before the column name (something like `T1.id | T2.user`) without changing the query (with a concat for example) ?

Thanks !

EDIT : So I've found an answer to my question. I'm using PHP function [mysqli_result::fetch_field_direct](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/mysqli-result.fetch-field-direct.php) which allows me to get metadata for each fields.

Thank you guys for all your answers !

Comment: i think that its not maters what the SQL return as long as you write in php code the order ex. `$id = $row['id']; $name = $row['user_id'];` or if OBJ Oriented: `$name = $obj->id; $id= $obj->user_id;`

Comment: In what language do you write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know the tables you're using, then you can add their name in your query :

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT('T1.', T1.id) as id, 
    CONCAT('T2.', T2.user) as user,
FROM T1
INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.user_id = T2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your question, you need to use an alias:

```
Select t1.id as UserID, t2.user as Username
From t1 inner join t2 on t1.user_id = t2.id
```